# Exibir <list> no DataGrid com 2 classes diferentes c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tenho duas classes PET e CLIENTE(Herda de PESSOA) 
`

```
    private int codPet;
    private string nome;
    private string especie;
    private string raca;
    private string porte;
    private string sexo;
    private string cor;
    private Cliente cliente; 


    public int CodPet { get => codPet; set => codPet = value; }
    public string Nome { get => nome; set => nome = value; }
    public string Especie { get => especie; set => especie = value; }
    public string Raca { get => raca; set => raca = value; }
    public string Porte { get => porte; set => porte = value; }
    public string Sexo { get => sexo; set => sexo = value; }
    public string Cor { get => cor; set => cor = value; }
    public Cliente Cliente { get => cliente; set => cliente = value; }  //AQUI EU GOSTARIA DE RETORNAR CLIENTE.COD

        public Pet()
         {
          cliente = new Cliente();

         }
```

`

CLIENTE/PESSOA

public class Cliente:Pessoa
    {
        public string email;

`

public class Pessoa
    {

```
    private int cod;
    private string nome;
    private long cpf;
    private string cep;
    private string endereco;
    private string cidade;
    private string numero;
    private string telefone;
    private string email;


    public string Nome { get => nome; set => nome = value; }
    public long Cpf { get => cpf; set => cpf = value; }
    public string Cep { get => cep; set => cep = value; }
    public string Endereco { get => endereco; set => endereco = value; }
    public string Cidade { get => cidade; set => cidade = value; }
    public string Numero { get => numero; set => numero = value; }
    public string Telefone { get => telefone; set => telefone = value; }
    public string Email { get => email; set => email = value; }
    public int Cod { get => cod; set => cod = value; }
}
```

`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz a busca para retornar uma list no DataGrid onde está o caminho da classe era para retornar *Pet.Cliente.Cod* ou seja só o código do cliente. Está trazendo a classe inteira.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma opção é substituir o método `ToString` da classe `Pessoa` ou `Cliente` para exibir a propriedade `Cod` ao invés do `Full Qualified Name`. Exemplo:

```cs
public class Pet
{
    public int CodPet   { get; set; } 
    public string Nome  { get; set; } 
    public string Especie { get; set; } 
    public string Raca  { get; set; } 
    public string Porte { get; set; } 
    public string Sexo  { get; set; } 
    public string Cor { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Cliente { get; set; } = new Pessoa();
}
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome     { get; set; } 
    public long Cpf        { get; set; } 
    public string Cep      { get; set; } 
    public string Endereco { get; set; } 
    public string Cidade   { get; set; } 
    public string Numero   { get; set; } 
    public string Telefone { get; set; } 
    public string Email    { get; set; } 
    public int Cod { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Cod.ToString();
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, ao gerar as colunas automaticamente, o resultado do objeto `Cliente` passa a ser o `Cod` retornado no `ToString`.

> Obs. Ignorei a classe `Cliente` utilizando apenas `Pessoa` para o exemplo

---

Outra opção é adicionar Propriedades a classe `Pet` para exibir o que precisa do `Cliente`:

```cs
public class Pet
{
    public int CodPet   { get; set; } 
    public string Nome  { get; set; } 
    public string Especie { get; set; } 
    public string Raca  { get; set; } 
    public string Porte { get; set; } 
    public string Sexo  { get; set; } 
    public string Cor { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public Pessoa Cliente { get; set; } = new Pessoa();
    public int ClienteCod { get => Cliente.Cod; }
}
```

Nesse caso, utilizei a anotação `Browsable` para a propriedade `Cliente` não ser exibida no `datagridview` mostrando apenas `ClienteCod`.

Comment: `public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Cod.ToString();
    }
}`
Deu super certo!!

Comment: Marque como resposta por favor =]